# send notification through c# WebApi to android using FCM

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, notifications

```
        var webAddr = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization:key=" + "My application ID");
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"to\": \"/topics/news\",\"data\": {\"message\": \"This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!\",}}";


            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

this is what I am trying but getting an error of

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the payload as follows it will work fine
{"to" : here is your token","notification" : {"body" : "new message new message ew essage new message new mw tech","title" : "Tesing596","icon" : "myicon","sound" : mySound",  "click_action" : "android.PS"}}